# Azure Stream Analytics - Start/Stop/Reset Window When Event Occurs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, windowing

I'm trying to build a rule in Azure Stream Analytic (ASA) job with this logic: "when a value is between X and Y, and it stays in that range for 1 minute, then output to service bus (then to Azure Function to send alert).  If the value is outside this range within the 1 minute window, window should be reset."

I've been reading windowing functions and it seems to me that a window starts when ASA starts, but I could be wrong.

Is there a way to start the (tumbling) window when a "bad value" event occurs and stop the window when the value turns to good (outside the range)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Stream Analytics, all Window functions are defined with a fixed length. In addition, Windows functions are defined in a Job. The only way to reset the window is changing the query of the Job and restart the Job.

> Is there a way to start the (tumbling) window when a "bad value" event occurs and stop the window when the value turns to good (outside the range)?

Based on your description, I think what you needed is raising event when the value is in a range for a minute.

[Sliding Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions#sliding-window) is more suitable for your requirement. It will produce an output only when an event occurs.